# Virtual function for printing generic linear linked list

Tags: c#, generics, singly-linked-list

I have an assignment to implement a linear linked list using generics in C# console application.

The class should also contain a `print()` method to print the elements of the list.
Conditions for Linear List are to be as a `long` type (`CNodeLong`) or `String` Type (`CNodeString`), both inherited from `CNode` with virtual function Print().

I have a problem implementing the printing method. I don't know where should it stand, and how to override it.

Here is my CNode class and CList class:

```
public class CNode<T>
{
    private CNode<T> next;
    private T item;

    public CNode<T> Next
    {
        get { return next; }
        set { next = value; }
    }

    public T Item
    {
        get { return item; }
        set { item = value; }
    }

     public CNode(T item)
        : this(item,null)
    {
    }

    public CNode(T item, CNode<T> next)
    {
        this.item = item;
        this.next = next;
    }
}

class CList<T>
{
    private CNode<T> first;
    private CNode<T> last;
    private int count;

    public CNode<T> First
    {
        get { return first; }
    }

    public CNode<T> Last
    {
        get { return last; }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return count; }
    }

     public CList(string strListName)
    {
        count = 0;
        first = last = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: "ASP.NET console application" - is pretty epic... I need to figure out if you need console app (so you can use `Console.Write` and like) or ASP.Net site (than need to sort out what you use to render WebForms,MVC,...)

Comment: :) It's a Console app, I can use Console.Write. But what confuses me is the virtual method, it is specified that it has to be virtual method

Comment: Side note: C# code generally does not use [Hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) - so for public samples you should consider not using prefixes like `C` in `CNode` (indeed if it is required for assignment it is trivial to rename it back with "rename" refactoring in VS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should override *ToString* method and add the virtual *Print* method to **CNode**.
(I've also added the *PrintList* method to **CList**):

```
public class CNode<T>
{
    ...

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return item.ToString();
    }
    virtual public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }   
}

class CList<T>
{
    ...

    public void PrintList()
    {
        CNode<T> current = first;
        while (current != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(current.ToString());
            current = current.Next;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can override the virtual method in the child classes:

```
public class CNodeString : CNode<string>
{
    public CNodeString(string item) : base(item) { }

    override public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Printing from CNodeString");
        base.Print();
    }
}

public class CNodeLong : CNode<long>
{
    public CNodeLong(long item) : base(item) { }

    override public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Printing from CNodeLong");
        base.Print();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution, but the assignment specifies to use virtual function. Is hat do-able?

Comment: of course, you can add the _virtual_ keyword to the _Print_ method: `public virtual void Print()`. But I don't see inheritance in your code. Where are you going to override the _Print_ method?

Comment: Well that's what's specified in the assignment. Conditions for Linear List are to be as a Long type (CNodeLong) or String Type (CNodeString), both inherited from CNode with virtual function Print(). If i have to create two other classes that inherit from CNode, how do i do it from the generic type?

Comment: @user3259357 - it looks like it is exact goal of your assignment "figure out how to create two other classes that inherit from Node using generics"... so you should to try yourself first. Hint: have you already solved the same without "generics" requirement? Stare at that solution for some time...